# Applying a gradient to a inclined div

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

**see the image in snippet having color gradient on some angle. I am unable to make color gradient from top to buttom **

> the child div should have background :linear-gradient(0deg, #FF6633 0%, #CC0066 100%), some inclined angle and color should be gradient from top to bottom.

*any solution
for parent div background :linear-gradient(180deg, #F1F1F1 0%, #FFFFFF 100%); ,
for child div background :linear-gradient(0deg, #FF6633 0%, #CC0066 100%) and some
inclined angle*

thanks.

```css
  .parent{
        width: 100%;
        height: 900px;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #F1F1F1 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    }
    .child{
        width:50%;
        height: 900px;
        float: right;
         background: linear-gradient(75deg  , transparent 50%, #FF6633 0%, #CC0066 100%);

   }
```

```html
   <div class=parent>
          <div class=child>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default body tag will have margin. we can remove that. please check the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<style>
   body{
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
   }
 .parent{
        width: 100%;
        height: 900px;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #F1F1F1 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    }
    .child{
        width:50%;
        height: 900px;
        float: right;
         background: linear-gradient(75deg  , transparent 50%, #FF6633 0%, #CC0066 100%);

   }
</style>
<body>
<div class=parent>
          <div class=child>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```